# HTML Page with AngularJS not rendering properly

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am brand new to AngularJS and I'm following an example from a book but am running into issues with the HTML rendering in a simple example. 
Code is working with no problems in JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/2436t/ 

I am running this in Firefox 30.0 and I just get the following output and no errors in Firebug 
[image]

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="controllers.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="HelloController">
        <p>{{greeting.text}}</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript (in external controllers.js file):

```
function HelloController($scope)
{
    $scope.greeting = {text:"Hello"};
}
```

I am sure I'm missing something simple but any help would be greatly appreciated,

Sean

Comment: Have you confirmed that `angular.min.js` is in the same directory as `controller.js` (like you have it)?

Comment: Yes, and Firefox is recognizing it.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing `ng-app="????"`

You also need to inject the controller in the module.

Here is the jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/yogeshgadge/2436t/14/

The HTML

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="HelloController">
        <p>{{greeting.text}}</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

The JS part

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('HelloController', 
  function($scope) {
    $scope.greeting = {
        text: "Hello"
    };
 }
);
```

Comment: Looks like the book was incorrect or may have been wrote for a way earlier version. Thanks.

Comment: it is possible to take a regular named function and define it as a ctrl or service but it is not much of a norm. also books may be of older edition.